# DataGrid Paging

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am using VB.Net 2005, with IE7.
I have a datagrid where I have set paging "AllowPaging" = True
However, when I click the link to the next page, the records are still the same.

My code is:

```
ds = SQLHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConn, 
      CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetInventory")
dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
dgInvestoryList.DataSource = dv
dgInvestoryList.DataBind()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What kind of DataSource are you using?  Please provide the code.

Comment: My code to load the datagrid is:

ds = SQLHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetInventory")

dv = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
dgInvestoryList.DataSource = dv
dgInvestoryList.DataBind()

Comment: Scarlet, what did you do to edit the code like that? I can't seem to get line breaks in my code.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Wizard with the SqlDataSource, then paying will be there all ready.

But if you go and place your code in the code behind you will have to do something like this - sorry i dont have the code for VB.NET - Must place code in the PageIndexChanging event. Use this [This link to change my C# code to VB.NET, i use it ALOT](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/)

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            this.GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Whats the difference between a dataview and a datagrid?

Comment: They are very similar, but cant tell u exaclty what the diff. is. But trust me, use a datagrid! Its alot easier and you can do alot more with it. Cheers and good luck